# How to fix Plugin Conflict Issue

Tags: wpmu, testimonials

We are using Strong Testimonial plugin on a wordpress website
Slider created with this plugin is working fine on homepage but when we add it to sidebar widget the slider wont work , So We have check using Health Checkup Plugin and We found that there is plugin conflict with WPMU Dev Dashboard

When i deactivate "WPMU Dev Dashboard" plugin the slider works fine in sidebar

**Reference:** https://www.loom.com/share/55e537e6bd1a4ee5a4cbc13e2dea9f2a

How i can fix this issue ?

- Check using Health Checkup Plugin
- tried by using jQuery migrate helper plugin